# MySQL: Sum Subqueried Columns

Tags: mysql, subquery, calculated-columns

Is there an elegant way to do this in MySQL:

```
SELECT (subquery1) AS s1, (subquery2) AS s2, (s1+s2) AS s3
```

or must I resort to

```
SELECT (subquery1) AS s1, (subquery2) AS s2, ((subquery1)+(subquery2)) AS s3
```

?

Thanks

**EDIT:** both subqueries yield integer results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use variables within MySQL

```
SELECT @query1:=(subquery) AS s1, @query2:=(subquery) AS s2, (@query1+@query2) AS s3
```

Still not that elegant. Perhaps you could elaborate on the subqueries so we could perhaps suggest better ways?

Comment: this is great, actually, but does it evaluate the subquery each time, or only the first time when set to a variable?

Comment: by my understanding it should only evaluate it once when it is put into the variable. You can actually create the vars in a different query and they persist for the connection. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html